# Occur: optional arg REGION usage

Tags: occur

I have 2 markers (created with `copy-marker`): `b` and `e` and I want to run `occur` for the string "foo" on the region between `b` and `e`. What's the correct syntax?

I tried:

```el
(occur "foo" 1 '((b . e)))
```

because the help says:

> Optional arg REGION, if non-nil, mean restrict search to the specified region. Otherwise search the entire buffer. REGION must be a list of (START . END) positions as returned by ‘region-bounds’.

but it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```el
(occur "foo" 1 '(((point-min) . (point-max))))
```

to try to understand the syntax, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting too much and e.g. not giving a chance to `point-min` and `point-max` to evaluate anything - ditto for `b` and `e` in your first attempt.

Try `(occur "foo" 1 (list (cons (point-min) (point-max))))` or `(occur "foo" 1 (list (cons b e)))` or use [backticks and commas](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) to allow the  selective evaluation of subexpressions: `` (occur "foo" `((,(point-min) . ,(point-max)))) `` or `` (occur "foo" `((,b . ,e))) ``